# Problem with homebrew installed to a different location(not to /usr/local)

Tags: homebrew, permission, development, apple-silicon, package-management

Being a standard user on Apple Macbook M1, I installed homebrew to (created Developer directory)

> $HOME/Developer/

using `mkdir homebrew && curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew`

and added to the path.

Tried installing mingw-w64 for c++ files using `brew install mingw-64` and after 15 minutes of brew downloading scripts it went on a loop with

> =>

and the M1 machine got really hot and eventually had to `Ctrl+C`.

`https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/664d0c67d5947605c914c4c56ebcfaa80cb6eca0/docs/Installation.md#untar-anywhere` says

> However do yourself a favor and install to /usr/local. Some things may not build when installed elsewhere. One of the reasons Homebrew just works relative to the competition is because we recommend installing to /usr/local. Pick another prefix at your peril!

What is the issue that made brew go into a loop while installing `mingw-64`? And is it possible to resolve this issue and download `mingw-64w` or other packages without running into issues using brew?

Comment: The standard path on M1 is `/opt/homebrew`. But, as the part from the documentation says: "Some things may not build when installed elsewhere. [...] Pick another prefix at your peril!". Is there a specific reason you can't install to `/opt/homebrew`?

Comment: @nohillside The owner/admin of the machine doesn't want any changes made by any other user. If I'm not wrong, installing to `/opt/homebrew` will make homebrew installed for every user?

Comment: As long as every user adapts their `PATH` accordingly, yes. But you need admin rights to install there. If this is work-related, you may need to demonstrate that you can't do your job withouth having Homebrew installed in the proper place.

Comment: @nohillside not really. This is my brother's first mac machine and I wanted to explore it without tweaking the system settings. Thank you for the information btw.

Comment: Homebrew doesn't tweak any system settings.

Comment: What exactly do you want to add via homebrew? A windows cross compiler looks to be somewhat advanced and not useful for exploring macOS

Comment: @mmmmmm I tried to compile a cpp file on mac. The file was running fine (i.e. without errors) on my windows machine but showed errors citing to an older version of C++ (such as `error: a space is required between consecutive right angle brackets (use '> >')` )

Comment: Then use Xcode/clang as is the mac way - gcc is not the normal Mac way

Comment: @mmmmmm the error i mentioned is coming when using clang on vscode.

Comment: Clang meets all c++ standards. Check the command. Line to make sure you are using the correct standard. That error is correct for c++04 I don't know  details of later standards